# Input file error in lumx

Tags: angularjs, lumx

In my directive, I'm trying to use the input file lumx but get the following error:

```
<div flex-item>
    <lx-file-input label="Browse..." id="files" ng-model="file"></lx-file-input>
</div>
```

> Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive
>   'lxFileInput' is non-assignable!
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=lxFileInput

Also, in the official documentation for lumx (http://ui.lumapps.com/directives/file-inputs), if you check in the console log, you'll see the same error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, if someone encounter the same issue. It must need value attribute, like this:

```
<lx-file-input label="Browse..." value="file" id="files" ng-model="file"></lx-file-input>
```